# Need help in formatting date in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB as db and trying to format date in below format

15-04-2022 i.e. DD-MM-YYYY

```
 select STR_TO_DATE('2022-04-15 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d') from dual
```

It is giving me output : 2022-04-15
When change SQL query like

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2022-04-15 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y') from dual
```

It is giving me NULL with error
Incorrect datetime value: '2022-04-15 00:00:00' for function str_to_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2022-04-15 00:00:00','%d-%m-%Y') from dual
```

and working properly.